# Who gets the permission when an app is registered in Azure Directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I created a **WebAPI** project in **Visual Studio 2019 Preview** and selected **Azure AD** to authenticate. I see in the Azure Portal that the app is registered and **Azure Active Directory Graph** is added under **API Permissions/Configured Permissions**. I added another permission called **user_impersonation**.

My question is, who has these permissions? Is this for another application like a **ASP.NET MVC** app which is not registered in the **Azure AD** to access this API? Or does this API gets permission to access other resources in the Azure?

**Figure 1:**

[image]

**Figure 2:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission you have given this app allows it to get an access token to that app in order to call its APIs.
And since it is a delegated permission, this app can do this on behalf of the signed-in user, so the token will contain the info for the app that asked for the token as well as the user.

The token is only usable against the app that defined the user_impersonation scope, nothing else.

Comment: When you said **that app**, are those two applications/APIs in the Figure 1 such as **Active Directory Graph** and the app below which has the ```user_impersonation``` permission. In other words the **source** app/API where I have this permissions set for to the two apps in Figure 2 which are **destination** apps?

Comment: Yes. Those would be apps that the app defined by the app registration would be allowed to call on behalf of the signed in user.